# How to override some methods inside of the installed plugin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-import-export

I am using django import-export and I am trying to override the forms.py to include additional options. I know in order to override django admin templates I need to create an admin folder inside of the templates/admin/base.html. The question is how would I do that inside for the plugin Forms.py

Comment: Overriding the plugin is pretty bad idea. Also please share what you have done so far. Thanks.

Comment: So far Inside of the of the import export plugin github I found  the forms.py that overrides django base_change_list.html and adds extra fields. I need to add additional choice field underneath but my question is how to access that file inside ofthe plugin. https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/forms.py